# Use of IS outside of <cfif>

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016, truthiness

I am not quite sure what this does.

```
<cfset User.ZeroBDK = FORM.ZeroBDK is "YES">
```

Is this short hand for

```
<cfset User.ZeroBDK = false>
<cfif FORM.ZeroBDK EQ "Yes">
     <cfset User.ZeroBDK = true>
</cfif>
```

Are there other truthy things that get set to true?

Comment: Why don't you throw some values at it and look at the results?

Comment: I don't even know what the edge cases would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(FORM.ZeroBDK is "YES")` expression will evaluate to `true` or `false` depending on what is in `FORM.ZeroBDK`,

so `<cfset User.ZeroBDK = FORM.ZeroBDK is "YES">`

will give to `User.ZeroBDK` a `boolean` value of true or false.

---

I'm just speculating..., but if you got this from some legacy code, it seems like not the best way to determine if `FORM.ZeroBDK` has something in it.

Comment: Is it a string only comparison?

Comment: are you trying to determine the exact string "YES" because `IS` is case insensitive and also `(1 is "YES")` will also evaluate to true?

Comment: It is definitely a string only comparison. But be warned the value `"Yes"` will be considered as a `boolean` value by coldfusion. So the expression `foo IS "YES"` will return a boolean true (`Yes` in ColdFusion) if value of foo is `1+` or `true` . I have tested this. [Demo](https://www.trycf.com/gist/2a5854c7e1effa59377b13510302c948/acf?theme=monokai)

Comment: *Is it a string only comparison?* Not really.  CF will do its automagic data type conversions. Meaning other values will evaluate to true as well, like "Yes", true, 1, -1, etc... If the goal is to accept *only* the literal string "YES", use `compareNoCase()` instead.

Comment: Correction, the strings `Yes`, `true`, `1` all evaluate to true. But `0`, `-1`, `100`, `""`, (space), `"Text"` all evaluate to false.  But numbers <> 0 do evaluate to true if used solo, <cfif NumberNotEqualToZero>true</cfif>`